# ImportError importing forms.py into models.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, python-import

I would really like to make a form instance a model attribute so that i have access to the form from the template through an object that I have handy.

When I try to import import any form into models.py, I get an ImportError on each of the import statements in the forms.py file which reference a model in models.py. I'm assuming this is due to circular imports.

I can't seem to find any information on importing forms into models. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing doesn't sound right, but if you want to do it you can embed the form import in the models' instance method like so:

```
class TestModel(model.Models):
    def get_my_form(self):
        from my_app.forms import MyForm
        return MyForm()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is exactly what I was looking for. Basically my app is generating a report with a bunch of items and the user needs to be able to dispute the item if the item meets certain criteria. This was the easiest way I could think of to associate the form with the report item for easy pre-population of the form with previously filled in data. The only other way I could think of was to do a mapping in the view which seems less straight-forward and less flexible. Thoughts?

Comment: I would preprocess this in the view or create a custom templatetag.